# Matching Two Point Function in momentum space using spherical coordinate

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, integration, greens-functions

#### Background of the problem:

The problem I am currently struggling is related to the momentum representation of Fourier transform. Briefly speaking, the integral in Minkowski under Cartesian coordinate is,

\begin{align} K(\vec x,\vec z) = \int^\infty_{-\infty} d^3y\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3} \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3} \ \bigg[ \exp[i \vec k (\vec x-\vec y)+i\vec p(\vec y- \vec z)] f(k) f(p) \bigg]. \end{align}
The function $f(p)$ and $f(k)$ is the fourier amplitude.
I know that this can be easily done by integrating over $d^3\vec y$ to give,
\begin{align} K(\vec x,\vec z) 
&= \int^\infty_{-\infty} d^3p\int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3}  \ \bigg[ \exp[i \vec k \vec x- i\vec p\vec z] f(k) f(p) \delta^3(\vec k-\vec p) \bigg]  \\
&= \int^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}  \  \exp[i \vec k (\vec x- \vec z)] f^2(k).  \end{align}

#### My problem

However, I cannot recover my result if I switch to the spherical coordinate. First I rewrite equation 1 in spherical coordinate,

\begin{align} K(\vec x,\vec z) = \int^\infty_{0} \int^\pi_0\int^{2\pi}_0 {r_y}^2\sin\theta \,dr_y \, d\theta \, d\phi \int_{p}\int_k \exp[i \vec k (\vec x-\vec y)+i\vec p(\vec y- \vec z)] f(k) f(p) . \end{align}

For clarity I simplified my notation by defining $\int_k = \int^\infty_0 k_r^2 \sin \theta_k dk_r d\theta _k d \phi $. Then, if we define $\vec q = \vec k - \vec p$, we have,

\begin{align} K(\vec x,\vec z) =  2\pi\int_{p}\int_k \int^\infty_{0} \int^{1}_{-1} {r_y}^2 dr_y d\cos\theta \  \exp(i q r_y \cos\theta )\bigg[ \exp[i \vec k \vec x- i\vec p \vec z] f(k) f(p) \bigg]. \end{align}
where I have used $i\vec q \vec y = iq_rr_y\cos\theta$ by choosing the polar axes of $\vec y$ to align in the direction of $\vec q$. First I integrate over $d\cos \theta$
\begin{align}
K(\vec x , \vec z) = 2\pi \int_k\int_p \int^\infty_{-\infty}  dr_y  \ \bigg[ \frac{r_y}{iq_r}\exp[iq_r r_y]\bigg]   \exp[i \vec k \vec x- i\vec p \vec z)] f(k) f(p),
\end{align}
and rewriting $r_y$ using $\partial / i\partial q_r $ and integrate over $r_y$ gives me $\delta(q_r)$ because of $\exp(iq_rr_y)$:
\begin{align}
K(\vec x , \vec z) = 4\pi^2 \int_k\int_p  \bigg[-\frac{1}{q_r} \frac{\partial}{\partial q_r}\delta (q_r) \bigg]  \exp[i \vec k \vec x- i\vec p \vec z)] f(k) f(p),
\end{align}
Using integration by part,
\begin{align}
K(\vec x , \vec z) = 4\pi^2 \int_k\int_p \ \bigg[ \frac{\delta(q_r)}{q_r^2} - \frac{\delta(q_r)}{q_r} \frac{\partial}{\partial q_r}\bigg]   \exp[i \vec k \vec x- i\vec p \vec z)] f(k) f(p).
\end{align}
Given $\delta (q_r)$, here I guess that I should integrate over momentum $k$.
In the end I would imagine that the result of this integration can resemble the "Cartesian result" in equation 2.
However, I am stuck with the divergent $1/q_r^2$ and $1/q_r$. I do not know where my mistakes are, or how this divergent term can be integrated.
I also tried with contour integral using residue theorem, but the result is not ideal because the line integral along the imaginary axes remains unknown.

I searched over the internet with key words combinations such as Green function, momentum space, spherical coordinate, two point functions and integral transform. But unfortunately I could not find anything similar to this.
Please also let me know if you know any trick about this integral or what this kind of problem is usually called.

Thanks in advance!